# filter html table results after clicking on dropdown entry

Tags: php, html, search, drop-down-menu, filter

i can filter my table after clicking on the populated  dropdown entrys from my sql table. By default the table shows me the results from the database from "finished" and "open". What i want is a static entry in my dropdown that shows me "all"  results additionally the "on going" result.

Here is my sql table:

```
+--------+------+----------+
|StatusID| name |  status  |
+--------+------+----------+
|      1 | TC   | open     |
|      2 | HTS  | on going |
|      3 | HTOL |finished  |
+--------+------+----------+
```

This is my html drop down with php code which provide the entrys from the sql table.

```
<th>
    <td>
        <label class="wmfg_label_a" for="chk_Status">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="StatusIDSuch[]" multiple="multiple">
            <option disabled selected value> </option>;
            <option value="alle" <?php if ($StatusIDSuch=="alle") echo 'selected="selected"'; ?>>alle</option>;                  
            <?php 
                foreach($result as $m)
                {
                    echo "<option value=\"" . $m['StatusID'] . "\">" .$m['Status'] . "</option>";
                }
            ?>
        </select>
    </td>
</th>
```

Here is the try to show me all entrys 1, 2 3 and not only my default 1,2  but it wont work. The important points are the lines with the word "alle".

```
if(isset($_POST['StatusIDSuch'])) {
    if ($StatusIDSuch == "alle"){
        $search .= "WHERE StatusID IN ('1', '2', '3')";
        var_dump($StatusIDSuch);
    } else {
        $i = 0;
        $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['StatusIDSuch']);
        $selectedOption = "";

        while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
            $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['StatusIDSuch'][$i] . "'";

            if ($i < $selectedOptionCount -1){
                $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
            }
            $i ++;
        }

        $search .= " WHERE StatusID IN (".$selectedOption.")";
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Show us your actual, complete query. Right now all I can see is that you're trying to select `StatusID` in a table that only contains `PK_ID`.

Comment: ditch the `if(isset($_POST['StatusIDSuch'])) {` part completely, and you will be able to see all

Comment: table edited. and .$search is added to the full query.

Comment: Also, please check your HTML markup. It contains errors (select and th elements aren't closed). If you use proper code indentation, you'll be able to prevent this in the future.

Comment: @cemal dunno if i understand you right, should i remove the part? The point is by default i want only shown the results open and on going.

Comment: I would suggest that you use client-side filtering instead. Basicly you select everything from your database by default. Then use JS to show / hide elements containing data that you want to filter. This will also save some resources on your server as it'll cost you a lot less queries.

Comment: @Daniel I updated my answer, please check and accept it if it solves your issue.

Answer (score 1):

according to your code, the variable `$StatusIDSuch` is not set before, so it can never be equal to `"alle"`,

```
if(isset($_POST['StatusIDSuch']) && is_array($_POST['StatusIDSuch']) && count($_POST['StatusIDSuch']) > 0) {
    $show_default = false;
    for($i=0,$count=count($_POST['StatusIDSuch']);$i<$count;$i++) if ($_POST['StatusIDSuch'][$i] == "alle") $show_default = true;

    if ($show_default){
        $search .= "WHERE StatusID IN ('1', '2', '3')";
    } else {

        $i = 0;
        $selectedOptionCount = count($_POST['StatusIDSuch']);
        $selectedOption = "";

        while ($i < $selectedOptionCount) {
            if (!is_numeric($_POST['StatusIDSuch'][$i])) continue; //only numeric values must be accepted to prevent sql injection
            $selectedOption = $selectedOption . "'" . $_POST['StatusIDSuch'][$i] . "'";

            if ($i < $selectedOptionCount -1){
                $selectedOption = $selectedOption . ", ";
            }
            $i ++;
        }

        $search .= " WHERE StatusID IN (".$selectedOption.")";
    }
}
```

for the build up of queries, below is better, faster and securer

```
if ($show_default){
    $search .= "WHERE StatusID IN ('1', '2', '3')";
} else {
   $vals = array_filter($_POST['StatusIDSuch'],'is_numeric');

   if (count($vals)) $search .= " WHERE StatusID IN (".implode(',', $vals).")";
}
```

Comment: Right.. sorry I missed that part cause I was looking at your code. My mistake!

Comment: i dont get results when i select "alle" and submit. The var_dump($StatusIDSuch) shows me array(1) { [0]=> string(4) "alle" }

Comment: After updating it seems I forgot the replace variable `$StatusIDSuch` with `$_POST['StatusIDSuch']`. I've corrected it now. And there's no `$StatusIDSuch` in the code that I'm posting as there's no need left for it.

Comment: IMHO, semantically using `alle` (german for all, right?) to show default `StatusID`s, may not be the best choice.

Comment: why is" alle" not a good word. but ive updated all like your code.
when i  echo $_POST['StatusIDSuch']; it says array, schould it not be filled with the value "alle" to show me ID 1,2 and 3?

Comment: I don't remember why I told it like that now, but if it suits you, then by all means go ahead and use it. Giving your select's `name` attribute as `StatusIDSuch[]`, tells php to set it as array, therefore using `echo` on an array or object will tell you the type of it(array in this case). If you select only `alle` , the `$_POST['StatusIDSuch']` will only have one value which is `alle`. And no, since the browsers and compilers doesn't know German or English, it will not fill that var with all values, unless you tell them to do with a programming language(eg. Javascript)

Comment: In any case I have already added necessary changes to my code to accommodate with those circumstances and if it works and does what you want, please select it as the correct answer.